# Sharing files between LXLE and Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows, lubuntu, file-sharing

I have a new Windows 10 (64-bit) desktop, that I'm trying to shift approximately 20GB of data to from a LXLE laptop.

I have successfully connected them with a spare Cat-5 cable (success = positive ping tests to/from each machine)

I tried setting up a Samba share but it won't mount the folder in LXLE and when I try to map the drive in Windows it says it can't connect due to SMB1 protocol.

I've tried modifying the smb.conf file but did not achieve success - though I feel out of my depth doing that and am not confident that I did it right.

I've also tried Nitroshare (can't get machines to recognize inside the program). Couldn't get the alternative sharing programs to install successfully on both machines.

I shut off the firewalls temporarily to ensure they weren't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about the most efficient File Transfer Protocol in the world?  (FTP)

```
sudo apt install vsftpd
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

add:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/home
```

` and then install FileZilla on the Win10 machine and download everything

Comment: IIRC, the Windows installer for FileZilla contains adware.  And doesn't FileZilla support sftp (ftp over ssh), which would mean no need to install anything on the Linux machine?